# How to do code splitting in CRA Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am working on a React App with typescript created from https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html and decided to take a look at code sppliting, currently I have all the components loading all at once on my app.js and instead I would like to kinda lazy load for each route request!

I have already had a look at : https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html and it does not seem to work for me. I get error like:
**Failed to fetch dynamically imported module** . Code looks like:

```
const ApplicantForm = lazy(() => import('../src/components/applicant/ApplicantForm'))
const Registered = lazy(() => import('./modules/Registration/Components/Registered'))
return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Router>
        <Wrapper>
          <Header />
          <Page>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
              <Switch>

                <Route path="/passreset-succeeded">
                  <PassResetSucceeded />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/kayttoehdot">
                  <TermsAndConditionsFi />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/privacy-policy">
                  <PrivacyPolicyFi />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/change-password">
                  <ChangePassword />
                </Route>
                <Route>
                  <PageNotFound />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/not-authorized" exact></Route>
              </Switch>
            </Suspense>
          </Page>
          <Footer />
        </Wrapper>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
```

Any idea why this is not working? Does this pattern works for CRA application, is there any thing i should enable, install or configure to make code splitting work?

Comment: Could you give more info on the error? particularly interesting would be the network log of resources the page tried to load...

Comment: Also, I'm assuming the components you are code splitting export the component as default?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner yes they are exported as default. there is no error under network tab, basically the issue is with import() it does seem to resolve to false!